# c++ mysql_fetch_field get variables name and type

Tags: c++, mysql, types, field, fetch

I'm trying to insert in the vector the name and type of the variables in my table. the language I use is C++.

Here is my code:

```
    std::vector<std::string> parameters;
    std::vector<std::string> types;
    request = "select * from " + table;
    //cout << request << endl;
    if(mysql_query(connection, request.c_str())){
    fprintf(stderr, "Impossible to get parameters: %s\n",
        mysql_error(connection));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    while (field_mysql=mysql_fetch_field(result)) {
        parameters.push_back(field_mysql->name);
        types.push_back(field_mysql->type);
        }

    for(vector<string>::iterator it = parameters.begin(); it != parameters.end(); it++) 
        cout << *it << endl;
    mysql_free_result(result);
```

the error I got:

> no matching function for call to std::vector<std::basic_string<char>::push_back(enum_field_types&)'

I think I got this error because type is integer and I declare it as string, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, that's the reason. You can fix it by implementing a function which translate the enum into strings, that is, if your goal is to print it.

Answer (score 0):

"i think i got this error because type is integer and i declare it as string, but i'm not sure."

You are absolutely right. Just make types a container for integers and your problem should be solved.